# Mpdf cannot function properly with mbstring.func_overload

Tags: php, laravel

I have used MPDF to generate PDF file and I got an error

> (Uncaught Mpdf\MpdfException: Mpdf cannot function properly with mbstring.func_overload enabled)

My PHP version is 7.1 and my operating system is centos. How can I fix this problem?

Comment: please share piece of code. It is difficult to help you with only header of error you get.

Answer (score 1):

Got your server `php.ini` and remove the semicolon character (;) in front of the line below-

```
extension = php_mbstring.dll
```

Then, restart your server. For more details, you can visit [this](https://www.knowledgebase-script.com/kb/article/how-to-enable-mbstring-in-php-46.html).

Comment: did you restart your `xampp` server?

Answer (score 0):

You can change your apache configuration (in my case it was in /etc/httpd/...).

```
<VirtualHost ...>
...
<Directory /var/www/website/folder/to/your/action/page/> 
   AllowOverride All
   mbstring.func_overload 0
</Directory>
...
```

Or you could change it for the whole website:

```
<VirtualHost ...>
...
<Directory /var/www/website/> 
   AllowOverride All
   mbstring.func_overload 0
</Directory>
...
```

Then restart apache using

```
sudo service httpd restart
```